# Asp.net mvc 4 регистрация

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. Подскажите какой-нибудь туториал как **грамотно** сделать регистрацию на asp.net сайте, чтоб всё было по уму, с базой данных и т.д. А то на каждом сайте всё разное, аж глаза разбегаются.

Comment: начните с [этого](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/12.1.php)

Comment: Воспользуйтесь готовым компонентом System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login ,  `<asp:Login>` просто ставится на форму. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login%28v=vs.110%29.aspx это пожалуй само проще